# Django filter data while signup according to country

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I'm making a project using Django and PostgreSQL. the user have to signup and after that login.

**Problem**

While user is `signing up` I'm asking different questions `like name, email` etc one field is `**Country(home country)**`. once the data store in database. now if the user want to login I want the he/she can `see all the data related to home country. e.g UK people can't see data from US or any other country and vise versa`.

Comment: please write exactly what is your question

Comment: @BaruchGans my exect question is that while sigining up into the website how can we filter the data according to countries. so when the user login after it so he can see only his country data. that how many people is register from his country etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can filter the **data** according to **user country**
*for example:*

```
user = request.user
data = *DataModle*.objects.filter(country=user.country)
```

Comment: i want to do something like this but everytime when the user login so then its not necessary to enter country everytime. but with this I have to make a field in login method. so that it filter data everytime

Comment: no it will get it from database

Comment: i made the code clearer